# How to find Specific parent on mouse click and get index inside top parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to find spesific parent div element. and i need get div index inside body.
now i have function to find specific element on mouse select or click.

this my code :

```js
$('div').mousedown(function(e){ /* get element selected */
      console.log(e.target);
 });
 
(function(){ /* get log message */
    console.log = function (message) {
        $('textarea').val(message.outerHTML)
    };
})();
```

```css
div {
  border : 1px solid black;
}
textarea { 
  width: 100%;
  color:white; 
  background:black;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p><b>foo bar</b></p>
  <p><u>foo bar</u></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
     <b><i>foo bar</i></b>
  </p>
</div>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of clicked `div` you can use `$(this).index()`. [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method search for a given element from among the matched elements and return  integer value indicating the position element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements..

```js
$('div').on('click',function(){ /* get element selected */
  console.log($(this).index('div'));
 });
```

```css
div {
  border : 1px solid black;
}
textarea { 
  width: 100%;
  color:white; 
  background:black;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div>
  <p><b>foo bar</b></p>
  <p><u>foo bar</u></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
     <b><i>foo bar</i></b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Marshall you can use `$(this).index('div')`

Answer (score 0):

function `javascript` not working if `textarea` move to top index

```js
$('div').on('click',function(){ /* get element selected */
  console.log($(this).index());
 });
```

```css
div {
  border : 1px solid black;
}
textarea { 
  width: 100%;
  color:white; 
  background:black;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div>
  <p><b>foo bar</b></p>
  <p><u>foo bar</u></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
     <b><i>foo bar</i></b>
  </p>
</div>
```